# Unable to Add Jproperty value in following format ["r0"]

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How to add a property ["r0"] in the below code? I tried to add escape characters to escape strings but was unable to.

```cs
JObject js = new JObject(
                        new JProperty("properties",
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("displayName", (object)jobject["properties"]["displayName"]),
                            new JProperty("description", (object)jobject["properties"]["description"]),
                            new JProperty("metadata",
                           new JObject(
                                new JProperty("assignedBy", "xyz"))),
                                new JProperty("policydefID", (object)jobject["id"]),
                            new JProperty("parameters",
                              new JObject(
                                   new JProperty("ringValue",
                                   new JObject(
                                new JProperty("value", "[r0\"]"))))))));
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a **string** with the text `"[\"r0\"]"`, or are you trying to add an **array** with one entry, a string with text `"r0"`?

Comment: @dbc yes, its an array value , added pseudo code up in question

Answer (score 1):

You seem like to be trying to create a Json Array. You need to use the `[JArray][1]` function to do that like this:

```
var jarray = new JArray("value");
jarray.Add(new JValue("r0"));
// If you need more values
jarray.Add(new JValue("r1"));
```

Then the value of `string json = jarray.ToString();` will be

```
[ 
   "r0",
   "r1"
]

Please share more information if it's something else you are trying to achive.
```

Comment: @Athanosios Kataras , yes its an array value, and added complete pseudo code in question, please let me know if can we append jarray to jproperty?

Comment: exactly like this ` new JProperty("value", jarray);`

Comment: ringValue": {
        "value": "[\r\n  \"value\",\r\n  \"r0\"\r\n]"